# Windows Script Host - there is no file extension in (variable)

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have this issue with my VBS script.  I'm getting an error of "There is no file extension in ""

The issue is I know how to launch the script by using double quotation marks, as this:

> shell "wscript ""C:\Users\First LastName\test1.vbs"" "

How do I pass to wscript as a variable for the path to the vbs file that has spaces in it?  For example, variable is 
myFile = "c:\Users\John Rodgers\test1.vbs"

How do I call script to run the vbs?

I've tried to no avail:

> Shell "wscript " & myFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shell Replace("wscript ""FILE"" ","FILE", myFile)
```

or

```
shell "wscript """ & myFile & """ "
```

Comment: Perfect.  This worked.  Thanks a million. I really appreciate it, Tim.